# cannot clear the cache in symfony2.1

Tags: caching, symfony-2.1

I have one rror when I clear the cache in my application,
and I think that is the cause of problem I encounter :
[image]

do you have any idea

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Does your app throw an error when you try to use the website? If not, try updating your vendors.

```
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar update
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a privilege problem (acces refuse = denied access).

You should try to run the cmd window as an administrator (right click -> run as administrator) and run the command again and/or give a look at the privileges on the cache folder and give your current user read/write/execution.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the same problem, but I don't know how to give a look at the the privileges on the cache and giving the user read/write/execution

Comment: it works now, I leat it manually, I deleted all contains of cache directory

Comment: Right click on the cache folder, choose properties. In the security tab you should have the list of users and permissions. If you want to keep it simple, give everyone (tout le monde in french) read/write/execute rights. This is not a recommended configuration in production.